# Errors while trying to buy Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I'm able to log into my Minecraft account on my phone, but I can't from my laptop. I'm using [this page](https://my.minecraft.net/en-us/login/) to log in. 
Is that the right one?

[image]

I tried to buy the Minecraft Java Edition on my phone, but, after entering all my details and pressing the purchase button, I get a message saying "*You need to enter a profile name*", even though I have entered a profile name, and [it is available](https://namemc.com/name/Kerndog73).

[image]

It feels like someone really doesn't want me to buy this game!

### Update

I was able to log into my account with the Minecraft launcher. I clicked the "*Buy the full version on the website*" button, and was able to log in within Chrome. However, I can't access my profile page.

[image]

What the hell is going on?!

### Update 2

I tried using Safari instead of Chrome and was able to access my profile. I'm still not able to buy the game though.

[image]

This is seriously weird.

### Update 3

I tried using Firefox and got a popup when I clicked the purchase button. So far, Chrome, Safari and Firefox have given me different errors. Is the Minecraft website broken or something?

[image]

### Update 4

I've tested 4 different browsers on 3 different networks and none of them let me buy this game. Maybe someone is trying to tell me that I shouldn't spend $35 on this.

Comment: Yes, that is the website. It seems like something is blocking website elements, maybe an ad blocker. I recommend using your phone as a WiFi hotspot and turning off all extensions in Chrome. BTW, this isn't really a gaming question, but it's very related and a good quality question, so I'll not vote to close.

Comment: @FabianRöling It might have something to do with extensions because I tried using Safari instead and got a little further. I'm still getting 404 errors when I type my name in the order page.

Comment: @FabianRöling I forgot to mention that I also tried hotspotting my phone but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Then maybe it's some firewall or antivirus issue on your computer.

Comment: Have you tried different payment method?

Comment: This seems like a much better question for Mojang Support. https://help.mojang.com/

Comment: As per Fabian's comment, I'd suggest temporarily disabling firewall and anti-virus software. And be sure that Javascript is enabled, which means checking browser plugins as well.

Comment: @Joachim I don't have any anti-virus software enabled. I know that JavaScript is definitely enabled (it's 2019!). I'm gonna try using PayPal.

Comment: @Zendy PayPal did the trick. Write an answer to claim the bounty. I feel kind of silly not trying this! Derp

Comment: @IndianaKernick, the screenshots in "Update 1" and "Update 2" contain your e-mail address. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @Marcono1234 Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I didn’t notice that it was there. I don’t really mind though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This often happens when your payment method is not available.
You could try to add your CC to Paypal and try paying using Paypal.

Answer (score 7):

Even if this question has an accepted answer, let me explain what those error messages mean.

First, I'm not that good on Javascript (the programming language that the page uses) and React (the framework being used).

#### Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886727/7620258), this indicates some formatting problem on the page source code. Nothing that you can do from your side.

Try to clear your browser cache.

#### Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

The 401 HTTP code indicates that you are not authorized to see a specific page. In this case, accessing the Mojang API (https://api.mojang.com/user). If you can log in, start with that.

If you keep getting this error, clear your site cookies.

#### Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768

#### SecurityError: Permission denied to get property "href" on cross-origin object

The page tried to load a JSON file from another website (Microsoft.com) and Chrome/Firefox didn't allowed it for safety reasons.

#### Failed to load https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/agent/minecraft/name/Kerndog73 resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

The page tried to check if your username is available, and it is. This should not affect the page.

#### Failed to load https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/agent/minecraft/name/Kerndog73 resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

The page tried to check your username again but did the request incorrectly and caused the "You need to enter a profile name" message.

#### XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace

The SVG image is not valid. This does not affects the page other than cosmetically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I believe it happens when your payment flow gets stuck in some weird state when your payment fails, it thinks your account has been created, but it can't retrieve your profile because your payment never actually went through. Then anytime after that your account is permanently stuck in this state. It's a bug on microsoft's backend.

I fixed this by creating a new account, if you're using gmail, you can still reuse the email you'd like by using an email alias like originalemail+minecraft@gmail.com if your email was originalemail@gmail.com.